# VBA Autofilter Dynamic dates based on Array

Tags: vba

I have been trying to create sub which creates array of dates for applying auto filter based on dynamic array but getting error while filter being applied.

> "Autofilter method of Range Class Failed "

work fines if I apply manually created array,

```
Private Sub CreateDateArayy()
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim PreRng, PostEng As Range
Dim src, tgt As Worksheet
Set tgt = Worksheets("Main")
Dim CellCount, x As Integer
CellCount = 0: x = 0:
Set PreRng = tgt.Range("C2:C16")

For Each cell In PreRng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
    CellCount = CellCount + 1
    End If
Next cell

ReDim myArray(CellCount * 2)

For Each cell In PreRng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
    myArray(x) = 2
    myArray(x + 1) = cell.Value
    x = x + 2
    End If
Next cell

d = testfilter(myArray)

End Sub

Function testfilter(dates As Variant)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Daily Data")
sht.AutoFilterMode = False
sht.UsedRange.AutoFIlter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=dates

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Got resolved by changing line

```
ReDim myArray(CellCount * 2)
```

to

```
ReDim myArray(CellCount * 2 - 1)
```